# Bitmap quality using glReadPixels with frame buffer objects

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap

I have the following issue when exporting a bitmap from frame buffer object on Android using OpenGL 2.

I have an image loaded into OpenGL and shown on the screen. The loaded image is bigger than the actual screen, thus I do some matrix manipulation to fit it on the screen.

Then I am trying to export the image back to bitmap of the original size and save it or show it on the screen. To achieve this, I create a frame buffer object, bind it to the current OpenGL context, "draw" the texture and use `glReadPixels` to create a `Bitmap`.

This is the original image (resized of course to fit here), which I can correctly see on my screen when I load it to OpenGL:

[image]

This is exported image (resized of course to fit here):

[image]

As you may see, the exported image has some darker areas. Am I missing any standard configuration?

I also get this issue on smaller textures that fit the screen. But the darker areas are a bit different -- instead one can see lighter dots.

I am sure this is not my matrix manipulation, since when remove matrix multiplication from my shaders, I still get this problem.

Comment: I would not expect glReadPixels() to be introducing the problem. My guess would be that the artifacts are introduced during scaling or texture sampling, but it sounds like you see this whether or not the image is scaled. Can you confirm that you're using a 32-bit color buffer, and that the problem appears when rendering 1:1?  FWIW, look closely at the bottoms of the numbers to see where you've lost some sharpness.

Comment: In addition to what @fadden already pointed out, you can also try calling `glDisable(GL_DITHER)`, and see if it makes a difference. I don't think it would for a 8 bit/component format, but most likely will if you're rendering to something like RGB565.

Comment: @fadden, how can I see if I am using 32-bit color buffer? And sorry about confusion with the sharpness, I scaled them manually -- first one comes from the screenshot and another one from other place, so they do not look exactly equal.

Comment: @RetoKoradi, you are right, I use RGB565 and adding `glDisable(GL_DITHER)` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `glDisable(GL_DITHER)` solves the problem.

Thanks @RetoKoradi.